# Changing motorcycle oil

Tags: honda, motorcycle, oil, oil-change

How do I change the oil on my motorcycle? I can see where to check the level, but how do I drain it? It's a Honda CB400 2011 model

Comment: you need to be a little more specific: what type of motorcycle are you asking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The bottom of the oil pan**

All of the CB series of motorcycles use a wet sump lubrication system and have an oil pan.

On your model specifically it is in the center of the oil pain and just a bit obstructed by the exhaust pipes.  You will need an extension and a 17mm socket to get to the drain bolt.

The drain bolt has a magnet, so you can check to see if there is any metal on magnet when you change the oil.  A sign there may be issues if you do.

**Torque Speck for Drain Bolt**

45Nm, or 33ft-lbs.

Answer (score 2):

---

If you cannot find it anywhere, look at the bottom of the engine. Remember, drain plug is usually at the lowest point of the pan. Look for a hexagonal bolt, and it should be it. Ensure to not confuse it with you transmission though.